# JSLink not working on view 'AllItems.aspx'

Tags: 2013, jslink

I'm trying to add a JSLink to the 'AllItems.aspx' view of a standard task list in SharePoint 2013. For this I'm using the following PowerShell snippet.

```
$SPSite = Get-SPSite "http://devserver/sites/mysc"
$SPWeb = $SPSite.OpenWeb()
$listViewUrl = $SPWeb.Url + "/Lists/Tasks/AllItems.aspx"
$SPView = $SPWeb.GetViewFromUrl($listViewUrl);
$SPView.JSLink = "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/all.js|hierarchytaskslist.js"
$SPView.Update()
$SPWeb.Update()
```

The JSLink information is saved but the JS file is not loaded when I refresh the list. When I add the JSLink to another view with the above snippet everything is working as expected. Does somebody know why it is not working on the default view?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Problem was related to the list on which I wanted to apply my JSLink file. Somehow the list seems to be corrupted.

Created a new list and everything is working as expected.